# Import managed solution from Customization Project

Tags: dynamics-crm

By default, an unmanaged solution is [imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8AdZ.png). Can we import managed solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. The idea behind managed solution is that you cannot download them from the system once they are deployed (because you could do that with any third-party tools, which you should not modify by yourself). You can only export unmanaged solution as managed and import this managed solution to some other environment. You cannot export this managed solution from this environment.